# Powershell enable WinRM remotely

Tags: powershell, ansible

I want to enabled winrm CredSSP from remotely to run the ansible script.

if I run this commands one by one in powershell window it works. but when I put all these in powershell script it not working.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName

Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force
Set-Item -Path "WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\CredSSP" -Value $true
Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1'))

Exit-PSSession
```

Any help to make this work as powershell script?

**Updated**

I copied the file remote server c:\temp dir. when I run the below code its giving this error.

```
Invoke-Command -session $session -Command {powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File c:\temp\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -CertValidityDays 3650 -EnableCredSSP -ForceNewSSLCert -Verbose}
```

**Error message**

```
VERBOSE: Enabling basic auth support.
Set-Item : The config setting Basic cannot be changed because is controlled by policies. The
policy would need to be set to "Not Configured" in order to change the config setting.
At C:\temp\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1:384 char:9
+         Set-Item -Path "WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic" -Value $ ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetI
   temCommand
```

I know this error message coming from the script, any help to fix this error message?

Thanks
SR

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error message, its not enabling the winrm on the remote machine when I run as script.

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use, you'll want to use `Invoke-Command` in a script instead: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Enabled-WSManCredSSP ...}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen will `Invoke-Command` work if winrm hasn't been enabled yet?  OP titled the question "enable winrm remotely".  Or is he asking how to turn on credssp on a box that's already winrm enabled?

Comment: @Colyn1337 I like to take care of both. let me test this and update the status.

Comment: I would use PsExec

Comment: @PowerCat can you post the snippet how your running power shell using `psexec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line failing in your ansible script is this, where it's configuring basic auth, not CredSSP:

```
$basicAuthSetting = Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic

If (($basicAuthSetting.Value) -eq $false) {
    Set-Item -Path "WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic" -Value $true
}
```

The quick fix is configure without Basic auth (maybe a space instead of a colon here):

```
c:\temp\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -DisableBasicAuth:$true -CertValidityDays 3650 -EnableCredSSP -ForceNewSSLCert -Verbose
```

---

The error in your question is saying that you have a security policy setting disabling Basic auth which overrides the `Set-Item` command. This is likely done by your domain admins, but can be a local setting as well. You can check for this in a few different ways:

```
# With the GroupPolicy module installed, run
Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -Computer $RemoteComputer -user $username -ReportType Xml -Path c:\temp\gpreport.xml

# Or run gpresult (on the remote computer)
gpresult /scope:computer /h c:\temp\gpreport.html  ## saves to a file
gpresult /scope:computer /v  ## outputs a huge wall of text
```

Either file should have an entry for `Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client` where `AllowBasic` gets set to `0`. This is just to confirm the reason it's failing - I don't recommend trying to change these policies.

---

As one of those security guys I have to recommend not enabling CredSSP delegation or Basic auth in a prod environment unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://adamtheautomator.com/enable-psremoting/),

You can use powershell to "enable"(start) the winrm service, and configure it. You will just have to use WMI to do so; and by WMI, I mean DCOM.

We will just use `Enable-PSRemoting` since it should do it all for you.

```
$SessionArgs = @{
     ComputerName  = 'ServerB'
     Credential    = Get-Credential
     SessionOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol DCOM
 }
 $MethodArgs = @{
     ClassName     = 'Win32_Process'
     MethodName    = 'Create'
     CimSession    = New-CimSession @SessionArgs
     Arguments     = @{
         CommandLine = "powershell Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList 'Enable-PSRemoting -Force'"
     }
 }
 Invoke-CimMethod @MethodArgs
```